# Sort data with hyphen in jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) plugin to display data. The first column has '-' between numbers. When I use below code

```
$('#table').DataTable({
   dom:'Brt',
   columnDefs:[{targets:'_all',type:'num-fmt'}]
});
```

the table is displayed like below

[image]

I want to display it in below order

[image]

Is there anyway we can display data in same format but sorted by not considering the '-'

Comment: i've added '-' for the "num-fmt" in jquery.datatables.min.js file. This solved the issue. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may implement custom search plugin for your datatype, based on numeric values of two numbers:

```js
//source data
const srcData = [
  {val: '1-1'}, {val: '10-10'}, {val: '100-100'}, {val: '2-2'}, {val: '20-20'}, {val: '3-3'}, {val: '2-1'}
];

//initialize datatables
const dataTable = $('table').DataTable({
  dom: 't',
  order: [],
  data: srcData,
  columns: [{title: 'Value', data: 'val', type: 'num-num'}]
});

//compare function
const compare = (a,b) => {
    ([ax,ay] = a.split('-'));
    ([bx,by] = b.split('-'));
    return parseFloat(ax) <= parseFloat(bx) && parseFloat(ay) <= parseFloat(by) ? -1 : 1
}    

//custom sort plugin for type 'num-num'
Object.assign($.fn.DataTable.ext.oSort, {
  'num-num-asc': (a,b) => compare(a,b),
  'num-num-desc': (a,b) => compare(a,b)*(-1),
});
```

```html
<!doctype html><html><head><script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script><script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></head><body><table></table></body></html>
```